# Why did my reputation decrease?

Tags: support, reputation, specific-question

I asked a question and no one answered me. And I repeated my question with more details.

[How to place an element over another element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492888/howcan-i-placea-div-over-the-img-responsive)

Comment: Someone clicked on the triangle pointing to the bottom at the left of your post.

Comment: Reposting a question (either because you didn't get any answers or didn't like any of the answers you got) is frowned on and typically attracts downvotes.  Lazy questions also attract downvotes.  Combine the two...

Answer (score 8):

Your reputation went down because you received negative votes. `-2` reputation per negative vote and `+5` for positive (if you are asking a question).

You can read more at:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation
**and**
 [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: Uhh... Wrong link.

Comment: @Undo, which would be the right one? please edit if you have it.

Comment: I don't have the right link, but the OP is on the *receiving* end of the downvotes. Not the downvoter.

Comment: @Undo, aha, got it. Good point. Changed now.